# Custom autoloader for project vs Composer PSR-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm currently working on a small framework which has the following directory structure:

```
/
-- app
-- vendor
   -- framework-vendor
      -- framework-package
         -- src
```

Currently what I have in my framework's composer.json are two PSR-4 instances:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "FrameworkName\\" : "src/",
        "": "../../../app"
    }
}
```

The goal of this is that the actual project located at `app` can use classes in the framework using `\FrameworkName\foo\bar\Class` but also its own classes using `\foo\bar\Class`. The only limitation to this is the relative depth between the vendor directory and the app directory.

What's the best way to do this? Just include a second autoloader or enforce this directory structure and let Composer take care of generating the autoloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to not force relative path depth is to use the autoloader returned by Composer like this:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('', __DIR__ . '/app/');
```